# check class/element status after click

Tags: javascript

Assuming I am unable to see below code, I have no idea how long does the timeout set, and I am unable to change the original code

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){ 
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    document.querySelector('.old').classList = 'old new';

}, 100);
});
```

```html
<div class="old">OLD</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

What I'd like to achieve is that once the `new` class is added then I want to change the `TEXT` line, the hack code as below

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){ 
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    document.querySelector('.old').classList = 'old new';

}, 100);
});

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){ 
   if(document.querySelectorAll('.new').length !== 0) {
       document.querySelector('.old').innerText = "123"
   }
});
```

```html
<div class="old">OLD</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){ 
     if(document.querySelectorAll('.new').length !== 0) {
        document.querySelector('.old').innerText = "123"
     }
  });
```

Since I am unable to know how long the timeout secs, so my first click won't work as it executes right away. So I have to add the timeout seconds bigger than the original. Is there an efficient way to detected if `new` class is added? 
or timeout is the best solution for this use case? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use [`Mutation Observer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for this purpose:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('.old').classList = 'old new';

  }, 500);
});

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
      if (
        mutation.type === 'attributes' &&
        mutation.attributeName === 'class' &&
        mutation.target.classList.contains('new')
      ) {
        mutation.target.innerText = "123";
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    }
  });

  observer.observe(document.querySelector('.old'), {attributes: !0});

});
```

```html
<div class="old">OLD</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: Was about to post the same thing, this is the preferred solution

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a better solution. Thanks!

Comment: @olo, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Use ClassList API to get this done. As new class will be add after some time. If new class is not added to dom then you can't get reference of this node to compare. The ClassList provides a handy method to solve this issue. use `contains` method to check if `new` class added or not. If added then change the text.

use below code

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){ 
 if(document.querySelectorAll('.old')[0].classList.contains("new")) {
   document.querySelector('.old').innerText = "123"
 }
});
```

[Solution](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VVrrMp)

Comment: This only works if you click the button twice, it doesn't observe when the classList changes.